# Struts2 - Set project port on 80

Tags: java, struts2, port, constants

I want to set Struts2 Project to run on 80 port. I determined that it's possible to do by constant in struts.xml file. I already put constant there:

```
<constant name="struts.url.http.port" value="80" />
```

I doesn't work.

Comment: At least provide logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constant struts use to build URLs. So this doesn't mean that your application server will start on 80 port. So the best way to run on 80th port is to configure your application server (tomcat, glassfish, jboss, jersey etc.)

Also if you use linux root privileges are required to use 80 port.

Comment: Ok, and could you explain what does mean "build URL" ? Thank you

Comment: it means that sometimes you need to get your application URL like http://somehost.com:80/mypage there can be port forwarding or proxy or load balancer. So to ensure that your url is correct you can set it in config. You may need that for redirection or smth.